# How to theoretically determine thermal emissivity of thin polymeric films?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, thermal-radiation, optical-materials, polymers

Maybe someone could help with determining gray-body emissivity of thin films such as polyethylene. There is a lot of conflicting data online with some sources stating polyethylene's epsilon value as 0.1 and other as 0.95. It is my understanding that thickness is the main factor and secondarily the additives (chiefly colorants) determine the thermal emissivity properties. Can anyone please help - I need to build a model and I am missing a value. I could even measure the value but don't know how to without expensive equipment...

Comment: I would not believe 0.1, not in the thermal IR. For your model, does it matter if it is 0.9 or 0.95?

Comment: See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235554061_Calculation_of_thermal_emissivity_for_thin_films_by_a_direct_method

Comment: Well it would really matter whether it is 0.9 or 0.95 but 0.2 and 0.9 would totally change the situation... I think that optical thickness does change the situation somewhat... I know that PE is even used as a optical window for some IR measurements....